# Отображение файлов на память

Tags: c++, winapi

Дано два файла, нужно переписать содержимое одного в другой. При этом надо переписывать по 1024 байта.

```
void FileCopy(int size)
{
HANDLE startMap, endMap;
HANDLE start = CreateFile(L"Test1.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
HANDLE end = CreateFile(L"Test2.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

startMap = CreateFileMapping(start, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
endMap = CreateFileMapping(end, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size*1024*1024, NULL);

     char buf[1024];

}
```

size - размер файла в мегабайтах. 
Запись должна производиться в массив buf, а потом в файл и так до тех пор, пока один файл не будет полностью скопирован, т.е. поблочное копирование. Застрял на этом моменте, не подскажите. как делать дальше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После `CreateFileMapping` вызывайте `MapViewOfFile` и получите указатель на отображение файла в памяти. Потом копирование и освобождение ресурсов в обратном порядке.

Comment: можно подробнее, как это сделать?  Толковых примеров использования MapViewOfFile не нашел

Comment: @IWProgrammer Пример в MSDN есть. Описание функции - тоже.